# Adblocking in Chrome without an extension

Tags: windows, google-chrome, adblock

Due to a policy change at work, Chrome Extensions have gone from a blacklist to a whitelist. As a result, I'm no longer able to install an adblocker and browsing the internet is horrific.

Working on the following key principles:

1. Whatever Chrome allows me to do, I can do
2. I don't want to circumvent the "no extensions" policy
3. I cannot redirect my internet traffic outside the organisation
4. I don't have administrator rights
5. I cannot download, install or run any software

what options do I have to make browsing the internet on Chrome as advert free as possible?

(I'm fully aware of the ramifications of working around an IT policy. Please just give me my options and I'll be the judge of whether or not it will be considered acceptable)

Comment: [How To Block Ads In Any Browser Without Adblock](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-block-display-ads-in-any-browser-without-adblock/). Haven't tried it but it might work. you can find the javascript mentioned in the link on [github](https://github.com/ArdaXi/AdSweep)

Comment: No documentation and no website isn't very promising and the last commit was 7 years ago. I suspect that it's probably dead :(

Comment: Connect your IT Department and ask them whenever one adblock solution is on the whitelist or to add one of the available solution do it?

Comment: Yeah I know, but all you gonna have is scripts that were eventually transferred to addons. adsweep was the first addon on chrome. I assume since then they stopped supporting the script. There are some videos on youtube, but I don't think you will find something well documented or official. Maybe ask your admin to install another browser like comodo dragon or brave?

Comment: I agree with the advise from @Seth but in case there's no ad blocking solution on their whitelist I'd recommend letting them know of https://adblockplus.org/deployments where they can find information related to company-wide deployment of Adblock Plus as well as a way to contact technical support. Note that I'm an Adblock Plus developer so feel free to check out whether other ad blockers have similar resources to help with large-scale deployments.